# How to parse a quoted search string using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a search string "cars 'cats and dogs' fish 'hammers'", what's the best regex for capturing all search terms.  It should support single and double quotes.  A Ruby friendly answer if possible.

Comment: what about nesting - `cars "cats 'and' dogs"`?

Comment: yes, this is another case that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 8):

Using `String#scan`:

```
irb> "cars 'cats and dogs' fish 'hammers'".scan /'.+?'|".+?"|[^ ]+/
  => ["cars", "'cats and dogs'", "fish", "'hammers'"]
```

Oh, and to get rid of surrounding quotes in the result:

```
irb> ["cars", "'cats and dogs'", "fish", "'hammers'"].map { |s| s.gsub /^['"]|['"]$/, '' }
  => ["cars", "cats and dogs", "fish", "hammers"]
```

Comment: That works and I can use it, but I'd like to do the job without the map.  I have a regex that almost does the trick but it's capturing an extra quote on quoted phrases: /("?)\s*\b(\S[^\1]*?)\b\s*\1/

Comment: `s.scan(/'(.+?)'|"(.+?)"|([^ ]+)/).flatten.compact` will exclude the quotes.

Comment: @Wayne, this doesn't work.  It drops all quotes, including those surrounding a search phrase like 'dogs and cats'.

Comment: @Gavin, From your previous comment, that's what I thought you wanted.  Sorry I misunderstood.  Your question has sample input; if it had the output that should result from that input, that would be good.

Comment: @Wayne, input: "cars 'cats and dogs' fish 'hammers'", output: ["cars", "cats and dogs", "fish", "hammers"]

Comment: @Gavin, Thanks.  That's exactly the output that my modification of @yjerem's code produces.  I'm using MRI 1.8.7.  Are you sure that the code is broken?